# How to calculate and spend funds received from derived addresses

Tags: bip32-hd-wallets

Assume I have a xpub for path `m/44'/0'/0'` and I generate receive addresses from it like `m/44'/0'/0'/1` to `m/44'/0'/0'/n` where n could get really large as time passes.

My question is:

Where does these funds really go? every single derived address has it's own value but do they sum up (likely in the higher tree level) ?
because wallets like [blockchain](https://www.blockchain.com/) show the total value of all generated values. what if all addresses have less than 0.2 BTC and I want to spend like 1.5 BTC .